# Private DNS not resolving for EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I just set up a VPN server using OpenVPN on an Amazon EC2 instance using this tutorial: https://hackernoon.com/using-a-vpn-server-to-connect-to-your-aws-vpc-for-just-the-cost-of-an-ec2-nano-instance-3c81269c71c2.

When I connect to my VPN server, the problem that I'm experiencing is that I am unable to connect with the private DNS:

```
$ssh -i X.pem ec2-user@ip-172-31-aa-bbb.ec2.internal
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ip-172-31-aa-bbb.ec2.internal: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

However, when I use the private IP address (still on the VPN):

```
$ssh -i X.pem ec2-user@172.31.aa.bbb
Last login: Thu Mar 22 18:43:34 2018 from 172.31.aa.bbb

       __|  __|_  )
       _|  (     /   Amazon Linux AMI
      ___|\___|___|
```

Would I be required to use a private hosted zone to achieve this? If so, is this something I can use alongside my current DNS provider (Hover)? I feel like I'm lacking a basic understanding of how this private hosting works, so details would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you're saying that you're unable to resolve the private DNS names from outside the VPC. You may need a DNS forwarder inside the VPC. See http://www.tothenew.com/blog/resolving-private-dns-queries-using-aws-vpc-resolver/

Comment: I'm inside the VPC when I connect to the VPN, no? @jarmod

Comment: I guess the terminology depends on how you view the combined network, but from my perspective your VPN client is outside the VPC and your network has been extended into the VPC. Anyhow, your VPN client is using local DNS. The VPC has its own DNS server (at the +2 address), so you need to use a DNS forwarder inside the VPC, and then configure your local DNS to forward certain DNS requests (those for AWS-hosted domains like ec2.internal) to the forwarder so that the VPC DNS can resolve them. The VPC resolver will not respond to queries from outside the VPC.

Comment: Another resource: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-set-up-dns-resolution-between-on-premises-networks-and-aws-by-using-unbound/

Comment: While studying for AWS certification I took the following note "Route53 has a security feature that prevents internal DNS from being read by external sources. The work around is to create a EC2 hosted DNS instance that does zone transfers from the internal DNS, and allows itself to be queried by external servers."

Comment: Is DNS resolution enabled inside the VPC? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-dns.html#vpc-dns-support

Comment: @strongjz yes, both resolution and hostnames are enabled.

Comment: what's the NACL for that subnet look like? is it allowing tcp/udp 53 out? Can you resolve anything else inside and outside the VPC, aka another private hostname and google.com.

Answer (score 1):

You need to append suffix in DNS at OS level

[image]

for detail please refer to URL: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/active-directory-ds/ad-design.html

Comment: Who assumes that the problem happens on windows?